# Визуализация связей в виде круговой диаграммы

Tags: python, python-3.x, графы, визуализация

Такой вопрос, можно ли на питоне сделать что-то похожее, учитывая что названия есть в переменной и связи считаются к примеру а не заданы произвольно. если да то подскажите пожалуйста где искать, с чем работать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/drawing.html)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Creating Circular flow charts (circos)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33388867/4279)

Comment: и да - спасибо за то что заминусили ответ, господа. В нем - два решения. Если ни руками ни стандартная библиотека не нравится - то что лучше? просто наминусить и не прокомментировать ЗА ЧТО?
элегантненько так ... По английски.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

да запросто - черепашкой.
"Детский" модуль [turtle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#module-turtledemo).
Только все ручками писать, если хотите на Python...
Хотя наверное хотелось готовую графическую библиотеку для визуализации [графов](https://habrahabr.ru/post/125898/)?
Тогда кроме NetworkX ничего в голову не приходит ))

Comment: я думаю не принципиально важно, главное чтоб было похоже, просто у меня есть dataframe с бинарной матрицей в котором название столбцов как раз соответствуют названиям элементов, и теперь нужно это визуализировать подобным образом.

Comment: тогда у вас есть шанс сделать прекрасную библиотечку под себя.
Тут все нарисовано "кругами".  Хотя прошу - перейдите по ссылке в моем ответе в слове "графов".  ))

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо! Будем разбираться

Comment: @ren: на Питоне полно библиотек (100k+), нет необходимости ручками популярные варианты визуализации реализовывать.  Попробуйте в поисковике ключевые слова: Chord Diagram python. Часто удобно Питон использовать, чтобы сгенерировать данные во входном формате для сторонней утилиты типа graphviz (если twopi circo для вас подходят) вместо рисования самого графика.

Comment: @jfs - да да. Только если поиск из 100к+ библиотек считать "бесплатным", а понимание найденных библиотек - мгновенным...   ах да  -  и результат должен точно подойти ))   Если 
например  -  всё должно быть именно "по кругу" как я вижу на примере, то не факт...

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите  библиотеку igraph.

Comment: @Jenssen, обоснуйте.